# Value of the foreign keys

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have a database named store. I have a table named users and inside that user table contains the username and password. Now have two types of users, the customer and the employee. What I am planning is to create a table for customer and the employee. What is the best possible way in creating a foreign key for both of them? They are both referring to the user table. Is it like

users table. userid, username, password, usertype?

if it is usertype then is it possible for it to be a varchar such as "customer" and "employee" and make it a foreign key for both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table to list the type of users with an id and a label :

```
UserType
--------
Id
Label
```

Insert your data in the table

```
INSERT INTO UserType VALUES(1, 'Customer') 
INSERT INTO UserType VALUES(2, 'Employee')
```

Create a table for your Users and add a column for the usertype.id

```
User
--------
Id
Name
Password
UserTypeId
```

Create your foreign key between User.UserTypeId and UserType.Id

Insert your data in your User Table

```
INSERT INTO User VALUES(1, 'John', 'password', 1) 
INSERT INTO User VALUES(2, 'Mike', 'password', 1) 
INSERT INTO User VALUES(3, 'Bill', 'password', 2)
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh so 1 and 2 defines that the user is a customer or employee right? this is exactly what i was envisioning! thanks sir. I have waaaaay too much things to ask soon as I am developing a mobile app that connects a website and im new to these things. thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct. The foreign key is the id in the UserType Table.

Comment: another followup question sir if i may. id like to create a table for customer and employee. what should i do to differentiate them and what foreign key to use?

Comment: Could you elaborate ? As far as I understand the question, the User table already fit that request.

Comment: so there is a customer table that contains userid, items and purchases while the employee has userid and stocks. so will usertypeid be there in both tables "employee" and "customer" sir?

Comment: you should not mix data that are related in the same table. Regarding your example, I think you are trying to make a shop of some kind. In that case, you should ahev a table containing the items to sell (with all their data). If those items are linked to an employee, then you add a foreign key in that table to the user table. The purchases are also an other set of data and must have their own table. You would then have the following tables : users, userType, products, and purchases.